# Why mutable not working when expression is changed in python ?

Tags: python

Here I am learning mutable concept using list in python,

```
In [114]: x=[1,2]

In [115]: y =x

In [116]: id(y)==id(x)
Out[116]: True
```

From above x and y sharing same state. I have observed two cases below,

1) Here mutable concept working because it shares same state,

```
In [123]: y +=[1,3]

In [124]: id(y)==id(x)
Out[124]: True

In [125]: y
Out[125]: [1, 2, 1, 3]

In [126]: x
Out[126]: [1, 2, 1, 3]
```

2) Here mutable concept not working because it didn't shares same state,

```
In [130]: y =y+[1,3]

In [131]: id(y)==id(x)
Out[131]: False

In [132]: x
Out[132]: [1, 2]

In [133]: y
Out[133]: [1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Why mutable concept not working second case ?

`y += [1,3]` and `y =y+[1,3]` are not equal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y += [1,3]   # Means append to y list [1,3], object stays same
y = y+[1,3]  # Means create new list equals y + [1,3] and write link to it in y
```

Answer (score 0):

no, they are not. `op=` (where `op` can be +, *, -, /, ...) are "in place" operators.

So they *modify* the left side of the assignment if they can.

`X op Y`, on the other hand, creates a new instance and puts the result there.

That means

```
 y = [1,2]
 y += [3,4]
```

is the same as

```
 y = [1,2]
 y.extend([3,4])
```

while

```
 y = [1,2]
 y = y + [3,4]
```

is the same as

```
 y = [1,2]
 tmp = list(y) # Create copy of y
 tmp.extend([3,4])
 y = tmp
```